# Derivatives with exponentials!

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a calculus test that I'm studying for but I've run into some problems! 
For one, the problem asks to compute the derivative of $f(x)= (1-2x)e^{-x}$.
I totally get that $\dfrac{d}{dx}e^{kx}=ke^{kx}$ but i'm not sure where to start in this problem! Help please? thanks!!

Comment: Start with the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **product rule**. Let $h(x)=1-2x$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$. Then you'll have $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$.
$$f'(x)=h(x)g'(x)+g(x)h'(x)\tag{product rule}$$
Then:
$$f'(x)=(1-2x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}\right)+e^{-x}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(1-2x)$$